# has_many through Rails association AngularJS 'POST' $resource, how to pass in array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am trying to pass in an array through AngularJS ngResource 'POST' but having trouble with it. ngResource doesn't seem to like arrays being passed in through params? Is there any way to get round this so the correct associations will be made?

Controller

```
ctrl.recipe = new RecipeService();

ctrl.ingredients = IngredientService.query();

ctrl.recipe.carbs = 0;
ctrl.recipe.fat = 0;
ctrl.recipe.protein = 0;
ctrl.recipe.ingredient_ids = [];

ctrl.addRecipe = function() {
 if (Auth.isAuthenticated()) {
   ctrl.recipe.$save(function() {
     var action = "created"
     alerts.recipeSuccessAlert(action);
     $location.path('recipes');
   }); 
 } else {
    alerts.loginAlert();
  };
};

ctrl.addIngredient = function(ingredient) {
  ctrl.recipe.ingredient_ids.push(ingredient.id.toString());
  console.log(ctrl.recipe.ingredient_ids)
};
```

Strong Params Rails

```
def recipe_params 
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :serves, :method, :time, :carbs, :fat, :protein, :meal_type, :user_id, :calories, ingredient_ids: []) 
end
```

Output

```
Started POST "/api/v1/recipes.json" for ::1 at 2016-04-29 12:19:52 +1000
Processing by Api::V1::RecipesController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"carbs"=>0, "fat"=>0, "protein"=>2, "ingredient_ids"=>["3", "2"], "title"=>"jklsad", "serves"=>4, "meal_type"=>"Breakfast", "method"=>"jkasljasdk", "time"=>"5", "calories"=>8, "recipe"=>{"title"=>"jklsad", "serves"=>4, "method"=>"jkasljasdk", "time"=>"5", "carbs"=>0, "fat"=>0, "protein"=>2, "meal_type"=>"Breakfast", "calories"=>8}}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
(0.4ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "recipes" ("title", "serves", "method", "time", "carbs", "fat", "protein", "meal_type", "calories", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "jklsad"], ["serves", 4], ["method", "jkasljasdk"], ["time", 5], ["carbs", 0.0], ["fat", 0.0], ["protein", 2.0], ["meal_type", "Breakfast"], ["calories", 8.0], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-04-29 02:19:52.029494"], ["updated_at", "2016-04-29 02:19:52.029494"]]
 (7.6ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 8.7ms)
```